# Ruby Search Array And Replace String

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, search, replace

My question is, how can I search through an array and replace the string at the current index of the search without knowing what the indexed array string contains?

The code below will search through an ajax file hosted on the internet, it will find the inventory, go through each weapon in my inventory, adding the ID to a string (so I can check if that weapon has been checked before). Then it will add another value after that of the amount of times it occurs in the inventory, then after I have check all weapon in the inventory, it will go through the all of the IDs added to the string and display them along with the number (amount of occurrences). This is so I know how many of each weapon I have.

This is an example of what I have:

```
strList = ""
inventory.each do |inv|
    amount = 1
    exists = false
    ids = strList.split(',')
    ids.each do |ind|
        if (inv['id'] == ind.split('/').first) then
            exists = true
            amount = ind.split('/').first.to_i
            amount += 1
            ind = "#{inv['id']}/#{amount.to_s}" # This doesn't seem work as expected.
        end
    end
    if (exists == true) then
        ids.push("#{inv['id']}/#{amount.to_s}")
        strList = ids.join(",")
    end
end
strList.split(",").each do |item|
    puts "#{item.split('/').first} (#{item.split('/').last})"
end
```

Here is an idea of what code I expected (pseudo-code):

```
inventory = get_inventory()
drawn_inv = ""
loop.inventory do |inv|
    if (inv['id'].occurred_before?)
        inv['id'].count += 1
    end
end loop

loop.inventory do |inv|
    drawn_inv.add(inv['id'] + "/" + inv['id'].count)
end loop

loop.drawn_inv do |inv|
    puts "#{inv}"
end loop
```

Any help on how to replace that line is appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry for not requiring more information on my code. I skipped the less important part at the bottom of the code and displayed commented code instead of actual code, I'll add that now.

EDIT #2: I'll update my description of what it does and what I'm expecting as a result.

EDIT #3: Added pseudo-code.

Thanks in advance,
SteTrezla

Comment: Hi it'd help us greatly if you could give some example data for the string - you're splitting on stuff and I have no idea why... can you please edit your question and add some sample data, and an example of what the result should look like with that example?

Comment: What mostly confuses me is that you have an empty string in `strList` - so there won't be any ids when you call split on that empty string, which means the loop will never be called

Comment: i get a feeling the code is way too complicated for the requirement. yet i am not able to completely gauge the requirement. a sample input and output would help a lot. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want #each_with_index: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index

You may also want to look at #gsub since it takes a block. You may not need to split this string into an array at all. Basically something like `strList.gsub(...){ |match| #...your block }`

Comment: Although this may work in my case, I'm not that experienced in the Ruby Language since the way I learned Ruby was looking at one file and figuring it out, then some research on some functions. I would really appreciate it if you could show me how to use this in my code. I know it sounds so noobish, then I can learn from what you show me. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell what more advice to give without knowing my about what this is supposed to do. Can you maybe pseudo-code what are you trying to do here?